# Appian UI automation

Tags: karate, ui-automation, appian

I am try to integrate the karate with #Appian low code platform application UI, facing some issue

1. failed to pass the dynamic data (except hard codded data)
2. failed to automate editable grid
3. failed to automate some UI component available only in Appian

Can any one give the solution to pass the data  dynamically  in ui automation

Comment: here is my personal opinion, this is a very loaded question and impossible to answer without knowing any specifics. since you are new here, please read this: https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask - now, dynamic data and all that is easy in karate, refer these answers: https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bkarate%5D+ui+dynamic - what I have heard is for applications like appian, if you are able to make a REST call to the backend and get some meta-data, it makes things easier. but you need to do some research. all the best !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

respond to failed to pass the dynamic data (except hard codded data)
you can try this, it worked for me
**data.json**
{
"username" : "ABC",
"password": "ABC@123"
}

**Feature file:**

- def data= read('data.json')
- def username = data.username
- def password = data.password

And input('input[name=un]', username)

And input('input[name=pw]', password)

Answer (score 0):

I  found one solution
We can pass our information like Scenario Outline and Examples format What we do as formal cucumber command
@tags1
Scenario Outline: Login with demo
Given driver "https://www.saucedemo.com/"
And input("//*[@id='user-name']","")
And input("//*[@id='password']","")
And  click("//*[@id='login-button']")
Examples:
|username|pass|
|standard_user|secret_sauce|
|locked_out_user|secret_sauce|

Comment: Even if the solution is mostly/essentailly code, find some words to describe the solution in English prose. Your code may seem obvious to you, but it may not be that obvious to readers of your answer.